# Without getting a meaasge how to send meassage to client in java spring web socket

Tags: spring, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am having a use case where I need to send message to client web socket from server and so in return client will return the client info to server. I am trying to do a reverse of client server technology in web socket, where client will first invoke the server to which server will respond back. Please someone let me know how to achieve this use case.

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 6455 client must initiate handshake. Only after handshake you able to send messages to client.